# Unable to install Health cloud package (Despite having licence and assigned to admins)

Tags: isv, health-cloud

We are facing issue while installing health cloud package. We are having licenses and its assigned to all the admins.

This is not first time I'm installing same. I have prepare more than 5-10 PDE/PEE orgs with Health cloud and extension packages in last quarter. So, I'm certain, all the pre-requisite steps are done.

Link to install package -
[Health Cloud Package](https://industries.secure.force.com/healthcloud/)

Issue -

1. (CareProgram.Monitoring_Duration_Days__c) Entity not available The Entity 'CareProgram' is not found. Contact the vendor for more details.

Anybody has its alternative workaround?

Comment: Is this specific to Summer'21 orgs or happens on all orgs?

Comment: It's on Sping'21 CS10 instance - https://status.salesforce.com/instances/CS10

Comment: You'll have to open a case with Salesforce.

Comment: @DavidCheng yes, I have raised a case also However SF support turn around time doesnt seem that much great. So thought to check with others as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with Salesforce support, license were provisioned but not enabled. Support guy did some changes with license editor it seems and after that it got working fine.